# The Dimension of Shortened Code

Tags: coding-theory

**Definition** $\,$  Given an $[n, m, d]_q$ code , and a set $R$ of $z$ indices ${i_1,...,i_z}$, the shortened code $R$ is the set of words from  which are zero at positions $i_1,...,i_z$ and whose zero coordinates are deleted, thus effectively shortening these words by $z$ positions. The shortened code $R$ has length $n−z$, dimension $≥ m − z$ and minimum distance $≥d$.

*My question:* Why the dimension of new code is $≥ m − z$.

Thanks

*Edition:* I want to answer to this question by coding theory terminology.

*First Case:* Consider $G$ is an generator of $C$. Let $z=1$. If the entries of $i$th column of $G$ be zero then the dimension of the new code is $m$ since we can delete the $i$th column of $G$. Consider there are some nonzero elements on $i$th column of $G$. By elementary row operations the elements $i$th column of $G$ can be zero except one entry. For simplicity, consider the first element of $i$th column of $G$ be nonzero.

Every code-word in $C$ can be obtained by this form

$$
(v_1,v_2,\cdots ,v_k)\times G_{k\times n}=(c_1,c_2,\cdots ,c_n)
$$
Now the desired code-words are in the form of $(c_1,c_2,\cdots ,c_{i-1},0,c_{i+1}, \cdots ,c_n)$ that just can be obtained by words in the form of $(0,v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_k)$. Therefore, the desired code-words can be obtained by removing the $i$th column  and first row of $G$ which means the dimension of the new code is $m-1$.

*Second Case:* Consider we want to get code-words that are zero in the two positions $i$ and $j$. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ are sub-codes that consist of code-words that are zero in $i$th and $j$th position which are zero. Then the dimension of the new sub-code are
$$
dim(C_1\cap C_2)=dim(C_1)+dim(C_2)-dim(C_1\cup C_2)\geq m-1+m-1-m=m-2
$$
Now by induction on $z$ we can prove other cases.

Comment: Deleting the zero positions clearly doesn't change the dimension. So you want to prove that the codewords of your old code that are zero at positions $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_z$ form a subspace of dimension $\geq m-z$. But this is basic linear algebra: The original code is a vector subspace of dimension $m$, and restricting any of the positions $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_z$ to $0$ means intersecting it with some fixed hyperplane. Intersecting a subspace with a hyperplane always decreases the dimension of the subspace by $\leq 1$.

Comment: Note that this holds for every linear code. So the reference isn't necessary.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for your useful comments. Is my edition a correct answer? (The difference between you and me is that you see the question from up but all time  I am thinking to  details).Thanks again.

Comment: I can't follow your argument at this moment; I am not quite familiar with your notations. But here is perhaps a simpler way to think of my argument: The original code is a subspace $C$ of the vector space $F^n$ (where $F$ is the ground field and $n$ is the dimension of the ambient space). Consider $k$ independent linear equations that describe $C$ (i.e., these $k$ equations are independent, and the set of their common solutions is precisely $C$). Then, $m = n-k$ (since each equation takes $1$ off the dimension of the space). Now, you are additionally requiring ...

Comment: ... the $i_1$-th, $i_2$-th, ..., $i_z$-th coordinates of your codewords to be $0$. This imposes $z$ additional equations. Hence, the dimension of the resulting code (which is described by $k + z$ equations in total) will be at least $n - \left(k + z\right)$ (indeed, "at least" because these new equations might not all be independent). In other words, it will at least be $m - z$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Interesting argument. I got it. Please make it as an answer to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok that you answer your own question, but you should post that as a proper answer (so that the question doesn't look as unanswered anymore, and people can vote) https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @leonbloy you right. Thanks